# Snake game head colliding into body scala

Tags: scala, error-handling

I am doing a snake game in scala, and i need to check when the snakehead collides into the body in order to be game over, but I get an error that the minus sign is an unresolved sign??? is there any way to separate the head (snakeTail(0))from the body and then check again if it does contain it.
This my array buffer var snakeTail: ArrayBuffer[Point] = ArrayBuffer(Point(2,0), Point(1,0), Point(0,0))

```
    def gameOver: Boolean = snakeHeadCollidingIntoBody

  private def snakeHeadCollidingIntoBody : Boolean ={
    if((snakeTail - snakeTail(0)).contains(snakeTail(0))){
      return true
    }
    false
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

I assume that `snakeTail - snakeTail(0)` is supposed to mean a collection with its initial element removed. Most collections don't work like that.

Try this:

```
def gameOver: Boolean = snakeTail.tail.contains(snakeTail.head)
```